# Fail to build to iPhone Swift Tesseract ocr

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tesseract

Tesseract OCR-iOS fails to build to iPhone 7 with Xcode, saying BITCODE ENABLED = True, but I turned it off.

The code works fine on software iPhone 7 simulator, but it says BITCODE ENABLED = YES when I try to build to the phone.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you try to clean your project ? Product -> Clean. Sometimes it can help

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue with Tesseract itself.

Here is the link for the issue: https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/issues/185

The issue is closed, but it looks like users are still facing it.

There may be a workaround: *update to the Master version of Tesseract (the last stable, 4.0.0, has some issues) and disable bitcode*. (artemisia-absynthium's comment in the above link).

Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this error too. You need select Pods from your project tree map, click on build settings and select tesseractOCRiOS on the left then set its enable bitcode to no. This will keep happening every time you run pod install though so I'd recommend adding this to your podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
```

Hope this helps